# LIKE and Equals not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently trying to find all users in a database where there is a left bracket `[` in the user name however when performing a query against the user table using the `LIKE` operator no rows are returned. If I use the equals `=` operator then rows are returned.

The issue doesn't appear when using the right bracket `]` or other special characters. I want to use the `LIKE` keyword as I eventually want to use the wildcard functionality to find all users in the table which the character in.

I have isolated the problem out to an example below. FYI Collation is Latin1_General_BIN

```
-- [ Not Working
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (UserID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT 'TEST[DEPT'
SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE UserID = 'TEST[DEPT' --Returns 1 row
SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE UserID LIKE 'TEST[DEPT' -- Returns 0 rows

-- ] Working
DECLARE @Temp2 TABLE (UserID VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Temp2 SELECT 'TEST]DEPT'
SELECT * FROM @Temp2 WHERE UserID = 'TEST]DEPT' --Returns 1 row
SELECT * FROM @Temp2 WHERE UserID LIKE 'TEST]DEPT' -- Returns 1 row
```

Comment: use ESCAPE KEYWORD in like operator.  ESCAPE ']'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the documentation for`LIKE`:

> Using Wildcard Characters As Literals
>
> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets.

So do this: `SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE UserID LIKE '%[[]%'` if you want to match all rows with a left bracket somewhere in the UserID.

Answer (score 1):

This is because SQL Server's `LIKE` doesn't comply with the SQL standard and uses an extended "pattern matching" that is a limited subset of a regular expression matching. And because of that the `[` has a special meaning in SQL Server (unlike standard SQL) so the `[` needs to be escaped.

So you need to use this:

```
WHERE UserID LIKE 'TEST\[DEPT' ESCAPE '\'
```

The escape character can be any character you want and it should be one that doesn't occur in the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE UserID LIKE 'TEST[DEPT'
```

The query `'delimits'` the **special character** with **square brackets**, telling the engine to treat it as a normal literal character instead of a character with special meaning.  **[Check here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html)** for more info.

Try something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE UserID LIKE '%TEST[[]DEPT%'
```